# How to support optional or empty FileField with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I added a new FileField 'photo' to my existing model and migrated the database. When I try to return data using DRF, I get the error message "ValueError: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it." Photo column contains empty values.

The field should be optional.

models.py:

```
def photo_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'photos/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
...
    photo = models.FileField(blank = True, editable = True, upload_to=photo_directory_path)
...

class MyModel_l10n(models.Model):
...
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_mymodel')    
...
```

serializers.py:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['photo']

class MyModel_l10nSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='mymodel.photo', required = False, allow_null = True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel_l10n
        fields = ['photo', ...]
```

views.py:

```
    res = MyModel_l10n.objects.filter(...)
    serializer = MyModel_l10nSerializer(res, many=True)
    return Response (serializer.data)
```

error message:

```
ValueError: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

EDIT: problem persists also I set the fields null = True and make the column null.
Also, including required = False to serializers.ReadOnlyField didn't help.

The problem only happens with MyModel_l10n. If I serialize MyModel, the missing file is not on issue.

Comment: Shouldn't the `FileField` have `null=True`?

Comment: @radoh I tested that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the ReadOnlyField to FileField with required = False, allow_null=True did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is raised when the photo field is not null, but has no underlying file on the file system. I think it might be related to the way you define the file field with **blank=True**. When done so, your model instances are saved with an empty value (not null) on the file field, and raises the exception when trying to get the actual file assicicated with that field.

You can try instead defining your field like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    photo = models.FileField(null = True, editable = True, upload_to=photo_directory_path)    
    ...
```

Comment: I tested also with "null = True" and made the fields null, but I get the same error message.

Comment: Did you re-run the migrations after doing so?

Comment: If that is the case, the issue could also be related to a problematic record, possibly caused by deleting a file associated with a FileField manually, or may be  related to a problem silently failing to save an uploaded file. Can you check that all instances with photo field not null have their related files existing in your file system?

Comment: Ozgur: yes, I ran the migrations. All colums are set to null.

Comment: @tputkonen can you also check that the associated files exist in the file system for all entries with photo field not null?

Comment: column 'photo' is set to null on all rows in the database.

Comment: I can serialize successfully an object of MyModel, but the problem happens with MyModel_l10n. So the problem is most probably with the serializer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201391/discussion-between-tputkonen-and-ozgur-akcali).